# React js conversion to typescript, adding data to const, interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have started working on react typescript. I am creating a drop down component using semantic ui. The problem is that semantic Ui provides code in java script format which is easier to understand. I need to convert the below code to typescript. I am successful in doing some of it but having problem converting handleAddition while adding new value to memberOptions.
Below is the code of JS.

I am not sure if I can use setState in typescript.

```
const memberOptions = [
    {
        text: 'Bruce',
        value: 'bruce'
    },
    {
        text: 'Clark',
        value: 'clark'
    },
    {
        text: 'Diana',
        value: 'diana'
    },
    {
        text: 'Peter',
        value: 'peter'
    }
];

class DropdownExampleAllowAdditions extends Component {
  state = { memberOptions }

  handleAddition = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState({
       memberOptions: [{ text: value, value }, 
         ...this.state.memberOptions],
    })
  }

  handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ currentValues: value })

  render() {
    const { currentValues } = this.state

    return (
      <Dropdown
        options={this.state.options}
        placeholder='Choose Languages'
        value={currentValues}
        onAddItem={this.handleAddition}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />`enter code here`
    )
  }
}
```

I need to convert handleAddition to typescript. are there some rules regarding them?

Comment: you can use the above code exactly in typescript. only changes would be import * as React from 'react'; and  class DropdownExampleAllowAdditions extends React.Component <any,any>{

Comment: I tried but its not working. The only issue I have now is with when adding value to MemberDropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is the solution. The trick is how you manage the state.

const options = [
    {
        text: 'Bruce',
        value: 'bruce'
    },
    {
        text: 'Clark',
        value: 'clark'
    },
    {
        text: 'Diana',
        value: 'diana'
    },
    {
        text: 'Peter',
        value: 'peter'
    }
];

interface Props {
    options? : any
}

export default class DropdownExampleAllowAdditions extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {options:{}};
    }`enter code here`

  const handleAddition = (e: {}, {value}: {value:string}) => {                
                        this.setState({
                            options: [{ text: value, value }, ...this.state.options],
                          })
                    }

  const handleChange = (e: {}, { value }: { value: string }) =>
                        form.setFieldValue(fieldName, value);

  render() {
    const { options } = this.props;

    return (
      <Dropdown
        options={this.state.options}
        placeholder='Choose Languages'
        value={currentValues}
        onAddItem={handleAddition}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />`enter code here`
    )
  }
}
```